# Why protected and private attributes are accessible by same class rather than by the same object?

Tags: oop, class, private, protected

For example, we have the class `Man`

If `Man.age` is protected, then I don't see why `chuckNorris` (instance of class `Man`) can change the protected/private attribute `age` of the object `jackBauer` (another instance of class `Man`). He shouldn't be able to do that (IMO).

In my mind, the **value** of a protected/private attribute is supposed to belong only to the **object** itself, not the **class**...

I need some explanation I think, I'm confused.

Comment: Your claims will be true or not depending on the programming language / platform. What language or platform are we talking about?

Comment: Java ? PHP ? Is there any difference ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP. But I am pretty sure there are differences between, say, Java, C++, Smalltalk and Eiffel regarding member access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matthieu is right. cuckNorris can do jackBauer.age

But there is no problem on that. If you are referencing Man instance attributes inside Man, that means you are coding Man class, so you know what you are doing.

The problem would be if you pass me that Man class and I could access the Man attributes with out knowing how Man class is coded.

Setters and getters may be doing some business logic that I don't know and I don't need to know. But the one who coded Mam does know.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this Java class:

```
public class Base {
  private int a
  protected int b;

  public Base(int a,int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  public int getA() {
     return a;
  }

  public int getB() {
    return b;
  } 
}

...
 Base foo = new Base(1,2);
 Base bar = new Base(3,4);
```

There is no way(maybe except via dirty reflection) the `foo` instance can change the protected or private variable in `bar`

You might allow it to if you want,

```
public class Base {
  private int a
  protected int b;

  public Base(int a,int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  public int getA() {
     return a;
  }

  public int getB() {
    return b;
  } 
 public void changeB(int newB,Base other) {
   other.b = newB;
 }
}
... 
Base foo = new Base(1,2);
Base bar = new Base(3,4);
foo.changeB(5,bar);
```

You can't protect the `changeB` method from altering stuff inside the `other` object [*], you just have to be careful about what your program does. With some languages you could have marked the `other` argument as unchangable , but not in Java - I don't find it a big deal.

[*} You could, by marking all the fields of `Base` as final, though then not even the instance itself could change the members after the object has been constructed.

Comment: Ok thanks that's clear. And I think this is just weird that foo can change bar.b even though b is private. I mean private should be related to the instance, not the class.

Answer (score 0):

A private attribute is accessible only by method in the class.
A protected attribute is accessibe in descendant class only. Therefore an object jackbauer can't modify anything private or protected in an object chuckNorris of class Man. Hope this would help

Comment: You say "A private attribute is accessible only by method in the class", then if jackBauer and chuckNorris are both object of the class Man, then they can share private attributes ??

Comment: In this case, it will be a class attribute which is shared by all objects of the class. These attributes are designed by the word static.

Comment: No I'm not talking of static attributes, in saying inside the object chuckNorris I can do : jackBauer.age. And I think this is weird because this is a private attributes, so other objects shouldn't be able to read of modify it. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Could you give me a code example? You cannot do that unless you had a public setter function for age.